# Setting email DNS on digital ocean for a gandi domain

Tags: email, dns

I bought kidkod.io domain name on Gandi, and I am trying to link it with digital ocean's DNS.

I set up an email redirection on gandi :

```
contact@   => forwards to : romain.jouin@gmail.com
```

- Gandi alert

Gandi display an alert on my email configuration, as follow :
"This domain is not using our LiveDNS nameservers. You can use Gandi Mail with any nameserver, but if you're experiencing issues with your email please refer to your DNS provider and ensure that the domain's DNS configuration contains the following records:

```
@ 10800 IN MX 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN MX 50 fb.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_mailcust.gandi.net ?all"
```

- Digital Ocean conf:

A the same time, I set up the Digital Ocean DNS to :

```
Type  Hostname      Value                                               TTL 
TXT   kidkod.io     returns "v=spf1 include:_mailcust.gandi.net ?all"   3600    
MX    kidkod.io     mail handled by fb.mail.gandi.net.50                14400      
MX    kidkod.io     mail handled by spool.mail.gandi.net. 10            14400      
A     kidkod.io     directs to 167.99.94.16                             3600   
NS    kidkod.io     directs to ns1.digitalocean.com.                    1800   
NS    kidkod.io     directs to ns2.digitalocean.com.                    1800   
NS    kidkod.io     directs to ns3.digitalocean.com.                    1800
```

Problem :

I don't receive any mail if I send one to contact@kidkod.io it get lost in the wild (and no error message back neither).

What do I do wrong ?
How to fix the issue ?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Nope, if you have a way, I would be interested ;)

Comment: The solution is simple. Delete all DNS records (using nameservers) on DigitalOcean and set all DNS records only on gandi.net. Use gandi's nameservers, not DO's.